# Backup power supply for car stereo

Tags: batteries, backup

[image: Photo] [image: Photo]I built a home stereo for my son using a car stereo and computer power supply. Unfortunately, I lose memory from the head unit every time the power is switched off. From what I understand, I need a 12V 1A supply during the time it is shut off. My idea was to place an inline (on yellow wire) charge and current source using capacitors or an rc battery. I need something small and am too hesitant of using LiPo batteries. I need help and don't know much about building circuits.

Comment: Do you turn off the ATX power supply completely with mains switch, or do you leave it on standby by using the PS_ON wire?

Comment: The psu is the main power bank. Once switched off, the unit is no longer supplied power.

Answer (score 2):

first, congrats on a good-looking stereo--i'd have loved that as a kid.

to preserve radio settings via "yellow" 12VDC wire:
how about using a separate 12VDC "wall wart" power supply
to keep voltage available.  you'll need to connect -/ground
to your stereo/power supply ground/common.

if you also want to preserve settings during utility power
failure, you'll need to also incorporate a battery/supercapacitor
solution.

hoping this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

If the radio really needs 12V @ 1A when off, any practical battery would quickly be destroyed (even rechargeable batteries have trouble with deep cycling).

However, it is likely that the radio, if shut, only needs a **few mA** to keep memory. You can measure that with a multimeter. If that is the case, then the smallest, least expensive battery would be a good choice.

Some car radio manufacturers suggest even a small [9 V battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-volt_battery) is enough to retain memory. **If** that is sufficient, put diodes in series with the supply +, and in series with the battery +, so that the supply does *not* charge the battery, nor the battery feed into the supply, but the battery *does* provide a small current when the supply is off. An inexpensive 9 volt alkaline battery would likely last a few years in such intermittent use, **as long as the radio is switched off before being unplugged** from the mains.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The head unit does include a rear usb. I've found usb rechargeable 9v batteries via Amazon. My concern is to the effectiveness and longevity verses utilizing capacitors. I'm also worried about failure and possible mishaps. Would you recommend the battery as the best option?

Comment: Do **not** plug a 9V battery into the USB port. The answer stated to put a small disposable (e.g., 6LR61, 1604A or 550 ) battery across the *power supply*, with diode isolation. If the head is removed, as opposed to power being shut, that is a separate issue.

Comment: Thank you. However, my concerns remain. I fear fire. He uses this product to play CDs and play guitar. My goal is to achieve memory storage and peace of mind. Anything tangible to this degree is greatly appreciated. I, unfortunately, don't comprehend the differences in 6LR61 and usb delivery for 'off' status. What I need is a dumbed down version I can understand. I apologize.

Comment: Also, my hope is to have a means to charge the backup supply while the stereo is in use, use the charge to keep memory until the next use and so on.

Comment: @Sterling, you state you, " don't comprehend the differences in 6LR61 and usb delivery." The 9 V battery would be in parallel with the **input** from the power supply, with diodes on each side, but the USB connector delivers 5 VDC **output** and does **not** power the radio.

Answer (score 0):

There were "memory savers" that plugged into the car's cigarette lighter (with a 9V battery) that did exactly what you want, used when changing the main battery.

These were not only for the radio though, so if the radio only needs a small amount to keep its memory you could check out using a rechargeable one.